# VS 2008 Dataset not viewable with GUI designer mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications, strongly-typed-dataset

Suddenly I discovered that my VS2008 stop viewing dataset in GUI designer mode, (just xml script). I do uninstall & install the VS, but no change, and no error message..!
Any idea to fix this issue ?

Comment: no problem!, I will answer my question by my self!
after 'googling' i found the answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1703949.aspx/1?DataSet+file+does+not+show+in+designer+mode

In Visual Studio Tools-> Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt, enter devenv /setup.
 thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no problem!, I will answer my question by my self! after 'googling' i found the answer
  [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1703949.aspx/1?DataSet%20file%20does%20not%20show%20in%20designer%20mode):

In Visual Studio Tools-> Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt, enter devenv /setup. thanks.